# Why cant i compile c in vs code?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, mingw

I have already install Mingw and do as the guide say. It can run the c program from cmd and works very well but when i open it from the vs code it doesn't work. When i tried to run it in vs code it always show this :

```
C:\Users\ASUS>cd "e:\TEST\" && gcc max.c -o max && "e:\TEST\"max
gcc: error: max.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Is there any solution to this problem ?

Comment: Yes, the solution is to provide the path to a C file that exists. Did you try using an absolute path instead of just `max.c`? Or did you try running the commands separately instead of joined with `&&`?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when I started using visual studio code. The reason is that the default shell in visual studio code is powershell, which doesn't check the current directory. To change the default shell to command prompt, follow these steps.

- Open vscode and enter the shortcut ctrl + `. After that you shall be seeing a windows like this. 
  [image]
- After that click on the drop down menu on right side of the prompt and then click on  `select default shell`.
- Here you should select `command prompt`, and after selecting it restart your IDE.